# Show whether f is Big Oh of g with logarithmic equations

Tags: big-o, complexity-theory, discrete-mathematics

[image]

Hello, how would you do whether f is Big Oh of g. I know how to do this for simple exponential functions but when it comes to logs, I have no idea what to do. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

You should use the [properties of the logarithm.](http://www.rapidtables.com/math/algebra/Logarithm.htm) For example, for your second case, you can use the fact that:

[image: formula]

So in big O notation:

[image: formula]

Regarding the first case, my advice is to [read this document,](http://www.bowdoin.edu/~ltoma/teaching/cs231/fall09/Lectures/2-growth-summations/growth.pdf) specially the section 4, labeled **"Growth Rate of Standard Functions"**, where you will find a bullet titled **"Any polylog grows slower than any polynomial"**.